# c# code for TabularTranslator (Mapping of source and sink columns) in copyActivity of an Azure Data factory pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I want to create an ADF pipeline with copyActivity but i am having difficulty writing the c# code for TabularTanslator (Mapping of source and sink columns) :

```
Translator = new TabularTranslator
                    {
                      // Mapping
                    }
```

Can somebody please the code?

Comment: Are these helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1d19485-7e72-46d6-a7db-85adcfdf3a0c/how-to-initialize-tabulartranslator-mapping-in-netc and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping.md#tabular-source-to-tabular-sink ？

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and add your sources and sinks inside it as `string` and `objects`.

for example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> mappings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
mappings.Add("source", new {
    name = "test",
    type = "string"
});
```

Then you can add the mappings object to the translator.